# how to return false on SoapFault Access denied

Tags: php, magento

how to return false on SoapFault Access denied error when login is incorrect?

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
```

i need return false to $sessionId if error.

Answer (score 0):

**Always set a default return** at the top of your function/method. 
That way to matter what the external forces are so long as there's no fatal error/syntax error you will have it return a value:

```
$vReturn = FALSE;
try
{
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
    $vReturn = $sessionId;
}
catch( Exception $oException )
{
    // log?
}
return $vReturn;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: i got same error on the $sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');